# neo4j multiple match merge making relationships fail

Tags: javascript, typescript, neo4j, cypher

I have node types a,b,c where each type can have 1 or more of every type (including its own type). In one transaction I MERGE all of the nodes from a file, then in the next transaction I MATCH nodes and try to create their relationships.

[image]

The following cypher statement succeeds with no failures, but also does not create the relationships I expect:

```
MATCH(a:TypeA) WHERE a.name = {nameA}
MATCH(b:TypeB) WHERE b.name = {nameB}
MATCH(c:TypeC) WHERE c.name = {nameC}
MATCH(d:TypeA) WHERE d.name = {nameD}
MERGE(a)-[:has_a]->(d)
MERGE(a)-[:has_b]->(b)
MERGE(a)-[:has_c]->(c)
```

[image]

If I narrow down the above cypher statement to the first match, any of the other matches, and a single relationship merge it works as expected such as:

```
MATCH(a:TypeA) WHERE a.name = {nameA}
MATCH(b:TypeB) WHERE b.name = {nameB}
MERGE(a)-[:has_b]->(b)
```

[image]

Is there a cypher format or limitation I am not aware of?

Comment: Can you find the `nameC` and `nameD` nodes by themselves? E.g., does `MATCH(c:TypeC) WHERE c.name = {nameC} RETURN c;` return a result?

Comment: @cybersam yes it does

Comment: Check the same for your last match to `d`, and note that you're using a `:TypeA` label in that line...is that correct or a typo? From what we've gathered so far, the first 3 lines match to nodes, so the remaining culprit is the MATCH to `d`. If that fails, then there are no rows left to execute the remaining Cypher. Also, you can PROFILE your query, look for which operation is resulting in 0 rows.

Comment: @InverseFalcon, the `d` match as type `:TypeA` is correct. a `-[:has_type_a]->` d is valid. being fairly new to cypher and neo4j i did not realize if it returned no matches on a single match statement it would stop execution. is that the correct way of thinking about it? if so, maybe i have to optional match the entire group as no relationships are guaranteed, but all are possible during my parsing.

Comment: That's correct. Cypher builds up records/rows and Cypher operations execute per row, so you get rows from the first MATCH, and per row the second MATCH executes which builds up more rows, which the third MATCH applies to etc. If a MATCH fails, then the row is wiped out (because the row didn't meet the conditions in your MATCH). If you are not sure if there are matches and don't want to filter, use OPTIONAL MATCH.

Comment: @InverseFalcon a different strategy I attempted was match then merge for each node type, but that caused different issues. Is that also a valid way of fixing this problem?

Comment: @Jordan.J.D Probably not, since once you hit a MATCH where no such node exists, there will not be a row to continue execution, so the rest of your query won't execute. Rely on OPTIONAL MATCH when you're not sure if a node exists or not.

Comment: @InverseFalcon sweet thanks, that likely solved my problem as I needed if you want to build an answer off of it for me to accept.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and after many time searching a solution I decided make an algorithm working:

```
origins = check if origin node exist, a count
MATCH (n:Namespace{name:'<nameNodeOrigin>'})
return count(n)
destinations = check if destination node exist, a count
MATCH (v:Value{name:'<nameNodeDest>'})
return count(v)

if (origins== 0 and destinations== 0) {
    CREATE simple
} else {
    if ( origins > 0 and destinations == 0 ) {
        MATCH (namespace:Namespace{name:'<nameNodeOrigin>'})
        MERGE (namespace)-[:rel]->(v:Value{name:'<valueNodeDest>'})
    } else if ( origins == 0 and destinations > 0)
        MATCH (value:Value{name:'<valueNodeDest>'})
        MERGE (n:Namespace{name:'<nameNodeOrigin>'})-[:rel1]->(value)
    } else {
        // Exists both original and dest node
        MATCH (n:Namespace {name:'<nameNodeOrigin>'}), (v:Value 
        {name:'<valueNodeDest>'})
        CREATE (n)-[:rel2]->(v)
    }
}
```

This algorithm insert a tuple nodeOrigin -relation-> nodeDest given existence of one/two nodes and their relationships.